# I want to connect to my server with jenkinsfile to execute some command

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I want to connect to my server and then clone the project from my repo to the server in question and do a docker build. Could you show me a template? Because with my own code it only does the build on jenkins. It doesn't connect to the server to do the pull.

`

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {

        stage('Pulling our project') {
            steps{
                withCredentials([gitUsernamePassword(credentialsId: 'GitlabCred')]) {
                    sh 'git pull origin jks'
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Building our project') {
            agent any
            steps {
                sh 'docker compose up -d --build'
            }
        }
   }
}
```

`